# Type bound procedure encapsulation

Tags: oop, fortran

How to pass an encapsulated type bound function? I played with the example from the Modern Fortran Explained book (Metcalf, Reid and Cohen) and this is what I did:

```
 module mod_polynoms_abstract

  use mod_geometrics

  implicit none

  type, abstract :: bound_user_polynom
   ! No data
   contains
    procedure(user_polynom_interface), deferred :: eval
  end type bound_user_polynom

  abstract interface
    real function user_polynom_interface(poly, pt)
     import :: bound_user_polynom, point
     class(bound_user_polynom)  :: poly
     type(point), intent(in)    :: pt
   end function user_polynom_interface
  end interface

  contains

 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  !Integral driver/chooser function
  real function integral(userfun, options,status)
   class(bound_user_polynom) :: userfun
   integer, intent(in) :: options
   real, intent(out)   :: status

   select case( options )
    case (1)
     integral = first_integral(userfun)
    case (2)
     integral = second_integral(userfun)
    case default
     integral = def_integral(userfun)
   end select

   end function 
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  !1. integration
  real function first_integral(userfun)
   class(bound_user_polynom),intent(in) :: userfun
    first_integral= 1.0 * userfun%eval(point(x=2.,y=2.,z=0.))
  end function  
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  !2. integration
  real function second_integral(userfun)
   class(bound_user_polynom),intent(in) :: userfun
    second_integral= 2.0 * userfun%eval(point(x=2.,y=2.,z=0.))
  end function  
 !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  !default integration
  real function def_integral(userfun)
   class(bound_user_polynom) :: userfun
    def_integral= 0.0 * userfun%eval(point(x=2.,y=2.,z=0.))
  end function  
 end module
```

This compiles, but when I run the program I get different results. 
When I call the function, maybe like this:

```
integral_result = integral(poly, 2 , status)
```

I get sometimes the right result, which is computed with the second_integral(userfun)
function. But sometimes the result is wrong.
The function can't calculate `userfun%eval(point(x=2.,y=2.,z=0.))` correctly, but I don't know why.
Is this the correct way to do this?

Edit:

I use :

*COLLECT_GCC=gfortran4.8 

COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.0/lto-wrapper

Ziel: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

Konfiguriert mit: ./configure --disable-multilib

Thread-Modell: posix

gcc-Version 4.8.0 (GCC)*

The correct result of *userfun%eval(point(x=2.,y=2.,z=0.))* is 0.962435484
So  *integral(poly, 2 , status)*  must give me 1.92487097.
But when I execute the program several times I got:

first run : 1.92487097 
second run: 54877984.0 
 ...      : 1.92487097 
 ...      : 2.55142141E+27 
 ...      : 4.19146938E+33 
 ...      : 1.95548379 
and so on ..

Edit 2:

The type polynom is defined as:

```
type, extends(bound_user_polynom) :: polynom
   real(kind=kind(1.0D0)), allocatable, dimension(:)            :: coeff
   type(monomial),allocatable, dimension(:)   :: monom
 contains
   procedure :: eval => poly_eval
   procedure, private :: p_add
   generic   :: operator(+) => p_add
   procedure, private :: p_subs
   generic   :: operator(-) => p_subs
 end type

!constructor
interface polynom
 module procedure construct_poly
end interface
```

and in my main program i call:

```
integral_result = integral(p(2), 2 , status)
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with the following information: Compiler name and version, what is the expected result, and what is the result that you get.

Comment: Where is poly defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error with some help from comp.fortan:

in:

*userfun%eval(point(x=2.,y=2.,z=0.))*

i had one uninitialized variable which gave me this strange results.
Is seems there is nothing wrong with the rest of the code.

Thank You,
Jan